# Best way to create a primary key - Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I am trying to build a project with ore data.
I want to build an ID for each entity, but I am not sure whats the best way to do it.
Now this ID would be that entity primary key (unique, not nil and mandatory).
Any tips please?

Note that I need this ID, once it exists, to be always the same.
I read somewhere that objectID "is temporary until either the object is saved for the first time or you call"...

Comment: Well you would need to describe the problem better to get a good answer. Approximately how many unique values do you want to store in CoreData? Many times just an incrementing integer is enough, but you might want a string or hash of the value for your problem.

Comment: I'd like a big ID. It can be Integer or a String :) as long as its unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, what are you looking for is `NSUUID().uuidString`.
For more information, check the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuuid).

Comment: That's it thanks. By the way, from what I've read it's almost impossible to get two equals NSUUID().uuidString. Can you confirm this?  I am doing just like this   let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString.lowercaseString

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, that should work fine for you case